# attempting to decrypt using crypto-js and nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, encryption, aes

I am communicated back and forth between a micro-controller and a nodejs tcp server.  The micro-controller forms a json string with sensor data.  The micro-controller then sends the json string to a WiFi module.  The WiFi module then encrypts the data using AES256 with 32 character Hexadecimal characters as the key before sending the encrypted data to the nodejs tcp server.

The nodejs TCP server is using the Crypto-JS module form of the googlecode Crypto-JS.

For testing purposes I would like to output the encrypted data and decrypted data to the console.  However I am unsure how do accomplish this.  I attempted to output the data, but I am receiving blank data.  For example, the console should read something like:
192.168.1.14:30001> some-json-string  Except I am receiving 192.168.1.14:30001>

Old Code:

```
  // I removed the old code to shrink this post and to remove any confusion.
```

***EDIT***
I am now using the the built in crypto module supplied by NodeJS.  The error I am receiving is:

> crypto.js:292   var ret = this._binding.final();
>                             ^ TypeError: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
>       at Decipher.Cipher.final (crypto.js:292:27)
>       at decrypt (C:\Users\joes\Desktop\encrypt\tcp.js:18:24)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\joes\Desktop\encrypt\tcp.js:44:23)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Socket. (_stream_readable.js:748:14)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:92:17)
>       at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:410:10)
>       at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:406:5)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:168:9)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)

Code:

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Load the Crypto Module
var crypto = require("crypto");

function encrypt(key, data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', key);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');

    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(key, data) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');

    return decrypted;
}

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

// Identify this client
socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort

// Put this new client in the list
clients.push(socket);

// Send a nice welcome message and announce
socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
broadcast(socket.name + " joined the chat\n", socket);

// Handle incoming messages from clients.
socket.on('data', function (data) {
  var key = new Buffer('85CE6CCF67FBBAA8BB13479C3A6E084D', 'hex');

  // Attempt to decrypt data with the above key
  var decryptedText = decrypt(key, data);
  //console.log("Decrypted Text: " + decrypt(key, encrypt(key, '{"resTemp":"82.19","roomTemp":98,"ph":58,"ec":700}>')));

  broadcast(socket.name + "> " + decryptedText, socket);
  //console.log(data);
});

// Remove the client from the list when it leaves
socket.on('end', function () {
  clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
  broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
});
// Send a message to all clients
function broadcast(message, sender) {
  clients.forEach(function (client) {
  // Don't want to send it to sender
  if (client === sender) return;
  client.write(message);
});
// Log it to the server output too
process.stdout.write(message)
}

}).listen(5000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 5000\n");
```

data should a buffered object and contain a json string, for an example:{"resTemp":"82.19","roomTemp":98,"ph":58,"ec":700}>
The ">" is there intentionally for data flow control between the micro-controller and the wifi module.  I will remove the '>' before I process the json string.

Comment: Why use a third party library when node.js has a built-in [`crypto`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html) module?

Comment: @mscdex, I tried to use the built in crypto modulr. However, I kept receiving an error.  I am AFK at the moment so I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Well, if you can reproduce the built-in `crypto` error, post it here (along with the code used) so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: Where is `decrypt()` defined? What does `data` look like? Is it a Buffer or something else ?

Comment: I edited my code again.  I by-mistakenly left out some important code.  The object data(I think is a js object) should output:
{"resTemp":"82.19","roomTemp":98,"ph":58,"ec":700}> The ">" is there intentionally for data flow control and will be removed before I process the json string.

Comment: @mscdex  If I am correct, data should be a buffer object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58838/discussion-between-dottedquad-and-mscdex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code using the built-in `crypto` module is almost correct. Notably there was a typo in `encrypt()` and the key needs to be a Buffer. Here's what I used:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

function encrypt(key, data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes256', key);
    var crypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'hex');
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');

    return crypted;
}

function decrypt(key, data) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', key);
    var decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');

    return decrypted;
}

var key = new Buffer('85CE6CCF67FBBAA8BB13479C3A6E084D', 'hex');

decrypt(key, encrypt(key, 'hello world'));

// outputs: 'hello world'
```

Comment: That code works as expected.  I attempted to alter your example to decrypt the data stream that is being sent to my nodejs TCP server without success.  I am receiving an error.  I edited my original post with the new code and the new error message.

Comment: To troubleshoot my issue I deactivated the wifi modules encryption.  I then send unencrypted json string to the tcp server and output the clear text and the length.  The length of the json string is a constant 52.  I also encrypted the json string and output the length which is a constant 128. I then decrypted the encrypted json string without issues.  I'm thinking there is an issue with the wifi modules encryption.  I will contact the vender and find out if there is a bug or if I'm doing something incorrectly. When i send encrypted data the length is always inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think the wifi module is defective. I think the issue that I am running into is how to handle flow control and I think the incoming data is getting converted to ASCII characters instead of staying in hexadecimal format.  What else can I do to debug this issue?